# Open a new tab in a browser with the response to an ASP request

Tags: http, asp-classic, jscript

It's a bit complicated this one...   Lets say I have a listing of PDF files displayed in the user's browser.  Each filename is a link pointing not to the file, but to an ASP page, say

```
<--a href="viewfile.asp?file=somefile.pdf">somefile.pdf</a>
```

I want viewfile.asp to fetch the file (I've done that bit OK) but I then want the file to be loaded by the browser as if the user had opened the PDF file directly.  And I want it to open in a new tab or browser window.

here's (simplified) **viewfile.asp**:

```
<%
var FileID   = Request.querystring ("file") ;
var ResponseBody = MyGETRequest (SomeURL + FileID) ;

if (MyHTTPResult == 200)
    { 
    if (ExtractFileExt (FileID).toLowerCase = "pdf")
        {
        ??????  // return file contents in new browser tab
        }        
....
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel points out you can control whether to open in a new window but not a new tab.  If the user has configured their browser so that new windows should open in new tabs (like I do) then you're golden.  If not it will open in a new window.  You can't control tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this.

```
<a href="viewfile.asp?file=somefile.pdf" target="_blank">somefile.pdf</a>
```

That way this opens in a new window/tab. Any server side language does not have control of the browser.

To serve it as a PDF, call

```
<% response.ContentType="application/pdf" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  What about the hard part of my question (returning the PDF as a PDF)!  So I'm sitting in my ASP page at the server with the contents of the PDF file (which I have retrieved from a third website) in the response body.  What do I need to do to it to send it back to the browser so that the browser "sees" it as a PDF?

Comment: Brilliant.  Works a treat.  For filetypes other than PDF, I set the ContentType to 'application/octet-stream'.  For some reason, the browser tries to open those files with Acrobat reader as well.  Tried it on FF as well as Chrome - same behaviour.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try serving those other files with their respective mime type.

Comment: Yes, but isn't 'application/octet-stream' a MIME type?  The other files are a filetype that doesn't have a MIME type and the intention eventually is to receive them in the browser with some client side JS and process them for display.  I can't because the browser insists on trying to render them to the Acrobat reader.  I expected with a Content type of 'application/octet-stream' I would at least get a file download dialog displaying in the browser.

Comment: Problem solved.  A combination of things, but mostly:

   - a wayward single quote inside the content type string "'application/pdf"
   - a call to toLowerCase, when it should have been toLowerCase ()
   - missing "=" in comparison, i.e. 
       if (Filetype = "pdf"), 
     which should have been 
       if (Filetype == "pdf")

I hate this language sometimes.